# Why does this code invoke the copy constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I'm a C++ noob so I can't figure out why the line in Logger.cpp invokes the copy constructor...

Logger.h:

```
class Logger {
    public:
    Logger();
    ~Logger();
};

Logger LOGGER;
```

Logger.cpp:

```
Logger LOGGER = Logger(); // Copy constructor here
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement `Logger()` creates an anonymous temporary object.

`LOGGER = Logger()` copies that anonymous temporary into the object `LOGGER`. The copy *constructor* avoids having to construct `LOGGER` as something other than a copy of that temporary.

The compiler is allowed to optimize away this copy, but it's not required to.  More [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor)

If you want to construct the object directly, just say `Logger LOGGER;`.

Comment: `Logger LOGGER();` ? Not `Logger LOGGER;` ?

Comment: Durrh.. yes, fixing that.

Comment: So, is the definition in Logger.h enough then? Seeing as it already says `Logger LOGGER;`...

Comment: @Motig:  I didn't notice that.  If one's at file scope and one's at local scope, then they'll be two different objects, the latter one shadowing the other in that scope.  I'd say `Logger LOGGER;` ought to be deleted from the header file if it's actually there and not an SO question editing error.

Comment: @JoeZ They're both in 'namespace scope' which is where I'd like the LOGGER to be, is that right?

Comment: I am guessing the real answer is, because compiler is allowed to use such conversion (as optimization), even though it might not produce the same output (which is a kind of golden rule). It is allowed, to assume the behaviour of copy constructor is the same as `operator=`. Then such substitution avoids creating unnecessary temporary objects.

Comment: @Motig:  If it's in a header file, I'd say mark it `extern Logger LOGGER;`, and then define it in a single .cpp file.  Otherwise, every .cpp file that includes this header will get its own definition of `LOGGER`.

Comment: @luk32:  The language gives you the flexibility to define the operators as you like, but the requirement that their behaviors are ultimately consistent with its expectations.  This gives rise to things such as the Rule of 3.  But, it also lets you do cool things such as swapping and sharing storage. `std::string` does a bunch of crazy stuff under the hood.

Comment: @JoeZ I'd say it's soft requirement, left to common sense. The thing is the compiler is allowed to make a substitution using completely different function. There is no real requirement they are consistent. This is pretty rare IMO. I am not saying it's bad. But when I 1st came upon this, I was like "Whoa, who guarantees this behaves the same?". Common sense it is. If it was requirement, compiler would need to make a test, `T t1; t1 = other; T t2(other); if (t1 != t2) VERY_BAD_THINGS;` or something similar. I don't think it does. It's pretty hard to test throughly too.

Comment: @JoeZ I mean in `c++` the rules for optimizations are pretty strict I would say. The observable behaviour of code must not change. There are very few exceptions. RVO is one, and this is the other one. I don't think I know any more. That is why I said it's rare and can be found surprising.

Comment: @luk32:  The joke about C was that it gives you enough rope to let you shoot yourself in the foot.  C++ takes that to a whole new level, since rope, shoot and foot could all take on surprising meanings if you're not paying attention.

Answer (score 3):

In the statement `Logger LOGGER = Logger();` the copy constructor is used.

Initially that seems surprising: you'd think that the assignment operator is used. But the language does not work that way. The reason is subtle: use of the assignment operator presupposes the existence of an object to which the assignment should be made. That would require default construction and that would be suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough code that to make some conclusion. It is not clear whether LOGGER in the header and in the module are defined in the same declarative region or in different declarative regions. In any case either the compiler shall issue an error or these two definitions define different objects for example because they are in different declaration regions.

Answer (score -1):

"Logger();" is returning an object, then the assignment operator is called, which is calling the copy constructor. The previous LOGGER object is passed as a parameter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not how things work. Why would `operator=` call copy constructor, when it can act on its own? The tricky part is, there is no assingment operator called.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds reasonable